# How to get multiple strings of starting with a string and ending with string in regular expression module of python?

Tags: python, regex

**What I want:**

- Suppose I give two strings to a variable by using OR operator. Like:

  ```
  command = 'windows go to books in d drive' or 
            'windows open books folder in d drive' or 
            'windows go to books which is in d drive'
  ```
- I want to get one word from here i.e. "books" from any three strings using regex module in python.

**What I have tried:**

```
import re
import os

command = 'windows go to books in d drive' or 'windows open books folder in d drive' or 'windows go to books which is in d drive'

if 'windows go to' or 'windows open' in command:
    non_greedy0 = re.compile(r'([go to ](.*?)[ in])|([go to ](.*?)[ folder])')

    output0 = non_greedy0.findall(command)
    print(output0)

    tuple0 =output0[0]
    print(tuple0)

    subfolder = tuple0[0]
    print(subfolder)

    foo = 'D' + ':/' + str(subfolder)
    os.startfile(foo)
```

**Output :**

```
[('ows ', 'ws', '', ''), ('go ', 'o', '', ''), ('to ', 'o', '', ''), ('ooks ', 'oks', '', ''), (' d ', 'd', '', '')]
('ows ', 'ws', '', '')
ows

File "***", line **, in <module> os.startfile(foo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'D:/ows '
```

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: how to choice the word that you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import os
from random import choice

command = choice(['windows go to books in d drive', 
                  'windows open books folder in d drive', 
                  'windows go to books which is in d drive'])

if 'windows go to' or 'windows open' in command:
    non_greedy0 = re.compile('go to (.*?) (which is ){0,1}in')
    non_greedy1 = re.compile('go to (.*?) folder')
    non_greedy2 = re.compile('open (.*?) folder')

    output0 = non_greedy0.findall(command)
    output1 = non_greedy1.findall(command)
    output2 = non_greedy2.findall(command)
    print(output0, output1, output2)

    if output0 != []:
        tuple0 = output0[0]
    elif output1 != []:
        tuple0 = output1[0]
    elif output2 != []:
        tuple0 = output2[0]
    print(tuple0)

    subfolder = ''.join(tuple0)
    print(subfolder)

    foo = 'D:\\' + subfolder
    os.startfile(foo)
```

I changed some code:

1. In Python, `or` is not used like this. `or` does not choice *randomly*; it chooses the first string that is not empty. `random.choice` chooses randomly.
2. The regex you used. the `[]` in regex means "any character in the group" which is not what you want: you want the full match. And also you regex didn't match 'windows open ...'
3. I used three regexes instead of one. This made the code better to understand. (and easier to debug!)
4. To find the subfolder name, I used `''.join(tuple0)`. That's because `tuple0` has length 3 (because there are 3 pairs of parenthesis in the regex), and 2 items must be empty strings. `''.join` solves the problem by joining the three strings.
5. In Windows, a backslash is used as path seperator instead of a forward slash.

Comment: Thank you so much ! But your code seems to not work. Your code's output of print(subfolder) line is "books which is". Instead, I wanted "books". Please get back to me.

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in the regex. I have edited my post and corrected it. It should work fine now. Please tell me if there are more mistakes in my answer. Sorry for the inconvenience. @TejasDhanani